# Deleting values in specific columns values of repeating rows

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe (df1):

```
First Name  Second Name Phone 
A                B       1     
A                B       2     
C                D       3     
C                D       4
```

I would like to hide column First Name and Second Name values only if they repeat, but the relevant different Phone column will stay in the succeeding row.

The result dataframe (df2) would be as followed:

```
First Name  Second Name Phone 
A                B       1    
                         2    
C                D       3     
                         4
```

Comment: Have a doubt.  The repeat values means whether it is `A A C C` only or `A C A C` or `A C D A` also, In the second case A and C repeats and in third 'A' repeats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `duplicated`

```
df2 <- df1
df2[1:2] <- lapply(df2[1:2], function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), ''))
df2
#  FirstName SecondName Phone
#1         A          B     1
#2                          2
#3         C          D     3
#4                          4
```

If the "repeats" meant only adjacent values

```
df2[1:2] <- lapply(df2[1:2] , function(x) replace(x ,c(FALSE, 
                              x[-1]==x[-length(x)]), ''))
```

In this case,

```
v1 <- c('A', 'C', 'A', 'C')
v2 <- c('A', 'D', 'C', 'A')
```

returns the full vector

```
replace(v1, c(FALSE, v1[-1]==v1[-length(v1)]), '')
#[1] "A" "C" "A" "C"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(FirstName = c("A", "A", "C", "C"), 
SecondName = c("B", 
"B", "D", "D"), Phone = 1:4), .Names = c("FirstName", "SecondName", 
"Phone"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```